# GORM criteria request

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria-api

Writing request that fetches all document entities that match different criteria
I have two requests that work and each of them return some results that are completely different: 
First:

```
def documents = Document.withCriteria {
            pproperty{
                user{
                    idEq uuser.id
                }
            };
    }
```

Second:

```
def documents = Document.withCriteria {
            loan{
                bank{
                    user{
                    idEq uuser.id
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

I'm trying to get the result of two in one query:

```
 def documents = Document.withCriteria {
        or {
           pproperty{
                user{
                    idEq uuser.id
                }
            };
            loan{
                bank{
                    user{
                    idEq uuser.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And I get an empty result set. What's wring with queries or it's a grails bug?

Comment: If you can reproduce that behavior in a sample app file a JIRA at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS and we will get it straight.  I expect there is something wrong in your code like curly braces not being matched up the way you intend, but if it really is a bug we can straighten it out.

Comment: I tried the same thing with HQL :         return Document.findAll(" from Document d where d.pproperty.user = :user or d.loan.bank.user = :user or account.bank.user=:user",[user:uuser])
 and it's the same. each OR part works in separate query but not all in one

Comment: If you can reproduce it in a sample app, please file a JIRA.

Comment: One thing that might help is set `logSql = true` in DataSource.groovy and inspect the generated SQL.